# do we need to allocate memory for linked list node?

Tags: c++, c, linked-list, malloc, free

By now I saw two ways to initiate a node?

1. ```
   Node c={6, NULL};
   Node b={3, &c};
   Node a={1, &b};
   Node *root = &a;
   ```
2. ```
   Node * new_Node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
   new_Node->data = 10;
   new_Node->next = &m;
   ```

which is better? And which is right?

Another question is how we can free the memory?

For 1, we do not need to free mem right?

For 2, for next pointer, `free(root->next)`, `root->data=NULL`, is this the right way to delete a node?

Comment: You should pick either C or C++, not both. In C++ one wouldn't usually use `malloc` and `free` like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct. First one relies on instantiating objects on stack and assigning them to a `Node *` and later one is instantiating objects on heap (using `malloc`).

`free` can be used for freeing memory allocated by malloc.

You are right in first case - you don't need to free mem.

In second case - linked list - create a wrapper over free in which you pass a `Node **`, traverse through the linked list until you get NULL node, save the next node and then `free` the current one. Finally and optionally you can set the argument as `NULL`.

Comment: The first is almost definitely *incorrect*. What kind of linked list implementation would possibly work with just stack variables?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Isn't that Ok if scope of linkedlist was in the function with this stack?

Comment: Yes, but what kind of linked list would use only a fixed number of nodes on the stack? I mean, it's certainly possible, but I can't say I've ever seen it, nor can I come up with a good use for it.

Answer (score 2):

For #1 you don't need to free memory. Local variables are on the stack.

```
free(root->next)
```

That will not free everything. That only frees one node.

Neither one is better or right. It depends on what you are trying to do. The deciding factor is whether you know how many objects you want to create before the program starts running. If you do, then #1 (creating local variables on the stack) is okay. For example, if you're sure you'll never have more than 100 nodes you can create an array of nodes of size 100.

```
Node NodeList[100];
```

If you don't know the size in advance you're going to have to manage nodes on the heap, using malloc/free;

Comment: Do I need to malloc space if I use NodeList[100]? Is it like int a[100], no malloc/new is needed?